# How to access downloaded files of one iphone app

Tags: ios, iphone, pdf

In my iphone app I am downloading pdf,mp3,jpeg data from server and storing in document directory. Now My issue is I want to access these downloaded files from another app like pdf reader and music app.But If i open pdf reader I can not find these data there can anyone please let me know how can I provide that feature in my app.

Comment: what is your saving file path ??

Comment: Apps can't access the files of other apps directly. You can use a `UIDocumentInteractionController` to let a user choose another app to open a file.

Answer (score 0):

You have to register your app for Open In feature.

[Here is the link](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/DocumentInteraction_TopicsForIOS/Articles/RegisteringtheFileTypesYourAppSupports.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40010411-SW1)

Comment: This isn't what the OP wants. This is the opposite of what is needed.